# How to change Exchange user's password in an automated fashion

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, change-password

I have an application that makes use of the EWS Managed API 1.2. Our admins of our Exchange Servers have been good enough to set us up with a mailbox assigned to our service account. All is dandy in connecting and doing the basic functions. The issue we have is that by policy they will not check the box for the password to never expire. Consequently we have to go through the effort in a manual process today to reset the password.

Our desire is to automate this password change so our application doesn't suffer any undo separation anxiety and so we don't have to suffer the burden of paperwork and co-ordination to have the password changed. Is there a way to change the password in an automated fashion?

EWS? SOAP? Powershell? ?????

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There could be other ways however you can create a scheduler task using Powershell script to run every 15 days and updating the password:

```
Set-Mailbox user_name@user_domain.com -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'new_password' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Once Powershell task is scheduled, it will run depend on setting and update the password to your account. You can also generate unique password string based on month or week pattern, or some other logic so don't need to remember and it will be different then the previous.

Comment: Set-Mailbox is only available "on-premises" from what I can tell. I have a computer with Remote Server Adminstration Tools (RSAT) installed, and can run commandlets like `get-aduser`, but not `set-mailbox`. Is there another way to change the password programmatically from the user's computer? EWS has a way to check if it's expired, but I don't see a way to do anything about it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple ADSI call to AD and invoke ChangePassword to do this as well.